# Google App Engine won't recognize facebook package unless I rename it

Tags: python, google-app-engine, facebook

I'm trying to intergrate Facebook Connect into an GAE app.  I've got a basic folder structure like so:

```
/gae-root
    /myapp
        /templates
        /etc
    app.yaml
    settings.py
```

and I tried to add the PyFacebook library like so:

```
/gae-root
    /myapp
        /templates
        /etc
    /facebook
        /djangofb
    app.yaml
    settings.py
```

I thought this would work, but now when I try to `import facebook` it throws a module not found error.  What's even weirder is that if I rename the directory from `facebook` to `foo`, the import now works but I'll hit errors later when I try to get the current logged in user.

Literally all I did was move the directory into my folder structure and try an import.  What am I missing?  Sorry if this is an easy question.

Comment: Is the facebook directory in your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: It's GAE, so *I believe* that, because it needs to be able to run in Google's environment, it doesn't matter if it's in my path because I can't set a path in Google's environment.  Make sense?

Also, I've added the path to "/gae-root" to my PYTHONPATH so that Eclipse can recognize stuff.

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` files in facebook and facebook/djangofb folders?  Or, maybe you have some broken facebook folders in your python site-packages folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with an extra .pth file in my site-packages directory.